# Using <input type="file"> in Django

Tags: html, django, file-upload, input, requesthandler

When someone clicks Submit after selecting a file with the `<input type="file">` element, how do I access the contents of the file in Django?

(It seems like the request sent to the request handler has no trace of the file anywhere -- not even in `request.FILES`.)

Currently my template is like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="file" accept="text/csv"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

View:

```
def HandleRequest(request):
  print "**** request:", request
```

I don't see anything being printed about the file.

#### Note:

There's probably other ways to do this in Django, but I'm looking a solution using the simple **`input`** tag, and **not** something else (which would probably involve Javascript).

Comment: Ah, you updated your post... please ignore my answer

Comment: According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) it should work.  Maybe post your view code?

Comment: The "other" methods are the right ones, as described in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs . You should define your file upload form in the model rather than directly in the HTML.

Comment: @George: Those may be better, but my method isn't "wrong", so I want to learn how to do things by hand before resorting to tools that automate it for me. If I don't know what a tool is doing, I usually don't use it.

Comment: What is the output of printing request.FILES?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Django is the wrong tool for you if you plan to "do things by hand." Django is all about automation of common task.

Comment: Wait, `enctype` is an attribute of `<input>` and of `<form>`? Typo?

Comment: @JackM: It's an empty dictionary.
@George: Thanks for the input, I'll keep that in mind. Though I really wish you could actually help, rather than just saying "urdoinitwrong"...
@Adam: ooh that might be something... lemme see...

Comment: @Adam: Nope, no difference... I still get `<MultiValueDict: {}>` for it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Could you pop in the Python chat room?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Comment: @George: actually, I find that Django is really nice precisely *because* it lets you do things by hand when you want/need to.  I remember reading something in the Django book to the effect of "almost all parts of Django are optional" because they don't want the framework to get in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted, as it is posted, works fine.  The HTML is sound (though I think the `enctype` on the `<input>` is redundant at best), and a very simple view shows an `InMemoryFile` after the POST.  The problem must lie in something between the browser and your view.  Some things to check:

- Middleware.
- Apache.
- Nginx.
- Decorators on your view.
- `mod_wsgi` configuration.

Comment: +1 I have no idea what happened, but after playing with some middleware stuff, it's working (though I'm not sure that's the issue... I think I missed something else but whatever). Thanks. :)